# WPF error: "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'DataGridRow' TargetType does not match type of element 'GridRowContent'."

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

This question/answer pair is of the type "share your knowledge, Q&A-style", designed to link this error to the most likely cause.

I hope it may be of use to some developers in the future.

Error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'DataGridRow' TargetType does not match type of element 'GridRowContent'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: 'DataGridRow' TargetType does not match type of element 'GridRowContent'.
        at System.Windows.Style.CheckTargetType(Object element)
        at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
        at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
        at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplatedParentValue(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, DependencyProperty dp, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
        at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplateNode(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, Boolean isDetach, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
        at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplate(DependencyObject container, Object currentObject)
        at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.HandleBeforeProperties(Object createdObject, DependencyObject& rootObject, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feContainer, INameScope nameScope)
        at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass6.<LoadOptimizedTemplateContent>b__3(Object sender, XamlObjectEventArgs args)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this particular error, the root cause was an incompatible style within a grid.

For example, if you see this snippet of code within a grid:

```
<grid:GridControl.View>
     <grid:TableView x:Name="tableView"
         VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Auto"
         DetailHeaderContent="Notification Tasks"
         AutoWidth="True"
         NavigationStyle="Row"
         RowStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"
         ShowGroupPanel="False"
         FadeSelectionOnLostFocus="False"
         ShowIndicator="False"
         >
     </grid:TableView>
</grid:GridControl.View>
```

Then, the error relates to the line relating to RowStyle. The RowStyle pointed to either cannot be found, or is of the wrong type for this grid. When WPF searches up the visual tree, it encounters an exception when it tries to apply the styling.

The error would be much clearer if it had said which line actually caused the error, rather than just implying that there seems to be an issue anywhere within each row of the grid.

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 + ReSharper, it will underline the offending line with a blue squiggle, indicating the source of the error. For the record, I have no affiliation with ReSharper, and there are many other good solutions which do exactly the same job, such as CodeRush, Visual Studio 2015, etc.